# cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'mylns:xsi' is not a valid value for 'NCName'

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

The Schema :

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="FileCreationList"/>
    <xs:element ref="DivestedExample"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="mylns:xsi" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

***The error:***

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - s4s-att-invalid-value: Invalid attribute value for 'name' in element 'attribute'. Recorded reason: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'mylns:xsi' is not a valid 
     value for 'NCName'.
    - src-attribute.3.1: One of 'ref' or 'name' must be present in a local attribute declaration.
    - s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_File' is invalid. Element 'attribute' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
```

Answer (score 3):

Attribute name declarations must be [**NCNames**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#NT-NCName) (non-colonized names):

> ```
> NCName ::= (Letter | '_') (NCNameChar)*  /* An XML Name, minus the ":" */
> ```

Remove the colons from `mylns:xsi` and `xsi:schemaLocation` to eliminate the error.

**Notes**:

- Do not include a namespace prefix in an XSD declaration of an element
  or attribute name.
- Do not declare `xsi:schemaLocation` as an attribute in an XSD; declare
  and reference the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`
  namespace:

  ```
  <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/name try.xsd"/>
  ```

Comment: For followers (i.e. myself) what this meant for me is "it must start with a letter, can't start with a number, but can contain numbers after the initial letter". Go figure.

Comment: @rogerdpack: Yes, another way one might get the sort of error in the question title would be to start an element or attribute name with a number, which is not allowed.  Only letters or underscores may begin element and attribute names in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you want to declare an element that uses attributes in a different namespace, then you need to (a) declare those attributes in a separate XSD document, with a different targetNamespace, (b) use xs:import to import that XSD document, and (c) reference the attribute declarations using `<xs:attribute ref="somens:localname"/>`.

However:

(i) Namespace declarations (xmlns:xx="uri") are not considered to be attributes and do not need to be declared (indeed, must not be declared) in the schema

(ii) Attributes in the "xsi" namespace are special - they are automatically allowed on every element, and should not be declared in the schema.